How to split character as per specific sequence?
Let's say I have a specific string in R, say "ABCDEFG".  I can break it into a sequence of say every two characters using the following regex.
 strsplit("ABCDEFG", "(?<=(..))", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "AB" "CD" "EF" "G" 

But I want to split it into a specific sequence.  First two characters then next one character, then again two then one and so on.
If my input string is "ABCDEFG" I want "AB" "C" "DE" "F" "G" as output (in last element there is only one element left).
How can I do it.  I do not want to count nchar beforehand as I want to do it dynamically.

What are the groups of letters which you want to find?

If you can't articulate the logic of the regex, then you can't write the regex.

while(j < nchar(my_string) )   ;  inside  foo[j] <- my_string[2*j:2*j+1]; foo[j+1] <- my_string[2*j+2]; j <- j+3

As TheDataMungerGuru says, " don't ask how to use XXX to solve;  ask how to get the desired result."   Regex is the wrong way to go about it.

@CarlWitthoft That's your opinion. OP asked for a regex solution and even if there are other options, tagging it with 'regex' is absolutely correct because 1.) It is very solvable with regex (using less code) 2.) Who reads the regex-tag is usually good in parsing 3.) If the regex-connection is removed, there is a higher chance, similar questions will appear here again because harder to find 4.) Annoying domination and subjective over-moderation of one guy.

We could generalize Edward's and rawr's ideas.
> spl_pat <- \(x, p) {
+   stopifnot(all(is.na(p) | p >= 0))
+   if (any(is.na(p))) return(x)  ## compatibility w/ strsplit()
+   if (identical(p, NULL)) p <- 1  ## compatibility w/ strsplit()
+   .spl <- \(x) {
+     pat <- rep_len(p, len=1 + nchar(x)/2)
+     start <- cumsum(c(1, pat[-length(pat)]))
+     stop <- cumsum(pat)
+     Filter(nzchar, substring(x, start, stop))
+   }
+   if (length(x) > 1L) lapply(x, .spl) else .spl(x)
+ }

Usage
Single strings, length(x) == 1L:
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', 2:1)
[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F" 
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', c(1, 4))
[1] "A"    "BCDE" "F"    "G"   
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', c(0, 4))
[1] "ABCD" "EFG" 
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', 1:1e3)
[1] "A"   "BC"  "DEF" "G"  
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', 2)
[1] "AB" "CD" "EF" "G" 
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', 1)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', 0)
character(0)
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', NA)
[1] "ABCDEFG"
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', NULL)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

Multiple strings, length(x) > 1L:
> spl_pat(c('ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFGHIJ'), 2:1)
[[1]]
[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F" 

[[2]]
[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F"  "GH" "I" 

Different patterns:
> Vectorize(spl_pat)(c('ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFGHIJ'), list(2:1, 1:2))
$ABCDEFG
[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F" 

$ABCDEFGHIJ
[1] "A"  "BC" "D"  "EF" "G"  "HI"

> Vectorize(spl_pat)(c('ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFGHIJ', 'ABCDEFGHIJ'), list(2:1, 1:2, 0))
$ABCDEFG
[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F" 

$ABCDEFGHIJ
[1] "A"  "BC" "D"  "EF" "G"  "HI"

$ABCDEFGHIJ
[1] ""

p < 0 probably wouldn't make sense, would it?:
> spl_pat('ABCDEFG', -1)
Error in spl_pat("ABCDEFG", -1) : all(is.na(p) | p >= 0) is not TRUE


Great answer. R core should include spl_pat in the next major update. +1

Thanks , I am waiting for a regex based approach though as I am hopeful it can be done through regex. Let's see.  Upvoted answer

Love this answer!! Beautiful coding. +1

@AnilGoyal  regex is the wrong approach.

You could use a vectorized substr function:
vsubstr <- Vectorize(substr)

x <- "ABCDEFG"

pat <- rep(c(1,2), length.out=1 + ceiling(nchar(x)/2))
start <- cumsum(pat)
stop <- start + rep(c(1,0), length.out=1 + ceiling(nchar(x)/2))

vsubstr(x, start, stop)

ABCDEFG    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 
   "AB"     "C"    "DE"     "F"     "G"


x <- "ABCDEFGH"
vsubstr(x, start, stop)

ABCDEFGH     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA> 
    "AB"      "C"     "DE"      "F"     "GH"

Not very elegant I admit. You could hide all of that ugly code in a function.
Two_one <- function(x) {
  vsubstr <- Vectorize(substr)
  pat <- rep(c(1,2), length.out=1 + ceiling(nchar(x)/2))
  start <- cumsum(pat)
  stop <- start + rep(c(1,0), length.out=1 + ceiling(nchar(x)/2))
  vsubstr(x, start, stop)
}

x <- "ABCDEFG"

Two_one(x)
ABCDEFG    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 
   "AB"     "C"    "DE"     "F"     "G"


substring is already vectorized, that could save you a step, x <- "ABCDEFG"; i <- seq.int(nchar(x)); i <- i + c(0, rep(i, each = 2)[head(i, -1)]); Filter(nzchar, substring(x, i, c(i - 1, max(i))[-1]))

Of course. Why am I reinventing the wheel??

Thanks , I am waiting for a regex based approach though as I am hopeful it can be done through regex. Let's see.  Upvoted the answer

Here is a base R solution using sub, gsub, strsplit, split and regex:
x <- "ABCDEFG"

x1 <- sub("\\.$", "", gsub("([A-Z]{2})([A-Z])", "\\1.\\2.", x))
strsplit(x1, split = "\\.", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]

[1] "AB" "C"  "DE" "F"  "G" 


Thanks , I am waiting for a regex based approach though as I am hopeful it can be done through regex.  Let's see.  Upvoted the answer

Well, isn't that a regex answer?

I do not understand the downvotes?

Yes exactly @TarJae, why are there so many downvotes?
